# Export data to Excel from Word or Txt

Tags: excel, ms-word, ms-office

I have around 1 Lacs records in .txt File, I have import them in Excel, But they are in one single column,Like:

```
Name:Value1
Address:Value1
Contact:Value1
Email:Value1

Name:Value2
Address:Value2
Contact:Value2
Email:Value2

Name:Value3
Address:Value3
Contact:Value3
Email:Value3
```

I want output, Like:

```
Name     Address     Contact     Email
Value1   Value1       Value1     Value1
Value2   Value2       Value2     Value2
Value3   Value3       Value3     Value3
```

I tried Transpose but didn't work...
Please help...

Comment: Have you tried writing any code to do this yet?

Comment: What if you do Text to Columns with a colon delimiter? That can get it into two columns which should be easier to transpose

Comment: That was just an example... There are only Values

Comment: No I didn't tried any programmatic approach...

Answer (score 0):

1. Download *Notepad++*, paste your initial text there.
2. Ensure that your blocks with identical values are separated by an empty lines (just like in your example)
3. Open *Search*->*Replace..* in Notepad++. Choose *Regular expression* in *Search Mode*.
4. Enter **\r\n** in *Find What* field and "**,**" (without quotes) in *Replace With* field. Click *Replace All* button.
5. Copy your text and paste it in to Excel using *Text Import Wizard..*. Choose *Delimited* and then *Comma* and then Finish.
6. Done.

Comment: Thanks Soulrider... It worked perfectly... :) But still I have to do a lot of Data Mining ;)... Well, Thanks again